# How to migrate Groups from user data store to WSO2 Identity Server?

Tags: wso2, usergroups, wso2-identity-server

We have an application which allows an admin to add user, groups, roles and permissions and has its own user data store which stores this information.

I have referred the official documentation of WSO2 IS https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+Roles+and+Permissions and found that there is a one to one mapping between groups in user store and roles in wso2 carbon.

We want to retain the functionality of Group Management in our app. So, is there any way to create and configure groups in WSO2 and assign the roles to those groups in wso2 Identity Server ?

Answer (score 0):

Groups in user store are represented as Roles in WSO2 IS. Basically each group in underlying user store is a Role in WSO2 IS. By adding an user store (I assume that your user store is an LDAP based one) to WSO2 IS will show the groups in that user store as Roles in the WSO2 IS. You can manage those roles either directly from the User Store or through WSO2 IS Management console.